# Can't upload app to virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

```
Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error).
In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

That's the pop-up I get when I try to run my app on the GenyMotion virtual device.

```
Installing com.example.engineering.app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.engineering.app"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.engineering.app
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

That's the console error message.

The odd thing is that even with a new clean "hello world" project I get the same error. It was working perfectly fine before I updated Android Studio. Something screwed up and I'm not sure what.

I've no idea what to do. I doubt it's GenyMotion related but who knows. I tried emulating a new device and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are running on API10 emulator. I also presume that you have tried removing the app yourself before trying to reinstall it. You are probably hitting 64k methods limit. Try running in say API19 emulator to see if you have the same issue.